# regex parsing / iteration

Tags: php, regex

How would I iterate through around 1,500 text files in a folder, each containing

> " Completion rate: 119 ( isComplete: 0 )\r\nFailure rate: 158 HC:
>   119-158-F "

and get "119" "0" "158" "119-158-F" out?
What would be the easiest way to do this? preg_match?

Comment: Yes, [`preg_match`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) is the way to go. Is there any other question? The linked manual page should get you there if you need an example.

Comment: How would I go through every file in a certain directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `glob` to iterate over the text files in the directory like below, though there are other options like `opendir` and `readdir` ...

```
$myDir = '/path/to/text/files';

foreach (glob("$myDir/*.txt") as $filename) {
  $str = file_get_contents($myDir . '/' . $filename);
  $pattern = '/^\s*Completion rate: (\d+) \( isComplete: (\d) \)\s*Failure rate: (\d+) HC: ([A-Z0-9\-]+)\s*$/';
  if (preg_match($pattern, $str, $match)) {
    var_dump($match);
  }
}
```

Comment: I've added a regex because of peer-pressure. However, there are a million different ways to write the regex depending on if the format of the data in your files ever changes ...

Answer (score 1):

Use preg_match_all() to put each match into an array.  Then you can print_r the array or implode it.

```
// Define regex
$regex = '/[^0-9]*([0-9]+)[^0-9]*([0-9]+)[^0-9]*([0-9]+)[^0-9]*([0-9]+-[0-9]+-[A-Z]+)/s'; 

// Open the directory containing your 1500 files
if ($handle = opendir('/path/folder')) {

    // Loop over each file in the directory
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {

        // Open the file
        $file = file_get_contents($entry);

        // Use preg_match_all to store each value in an array
        preg_match_all($regex, $file, $numbers);

        $numbers = $numbers[0]; // yes you have to do this part

        print_r($numbers); // Or implode instead
        echo '<br />';

    }

    closedir($handle);
}
```

Comment: I fail to see how `\d+` is going to match the required `119-158-F`

Comment: Whoops, didn't see he wanted to extract that whole bit.  Thought he just wanted each number.  Best way is to use Kisaro's regex in my script.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me just fine using a online regex tester:

```
    preg_match_all('/[^0-9]*([0-9]+)[^0-9]*([0-9]+)[^0-9]*([0-9]+)[^0-9]*([0-9]+-[0-9]+-[A-Z]+)/s');
```

It'll get you this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Completion rate: 129 ( isComplete: 0 )\r\nFailure rate: 158 HC: 119-158-F
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 129
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 158
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 119-158-F
    )

)
```